# How physical interaction/processes are connected with the information processing?

Tags: quantum-information, many-body, interactions, information

It is so hard to simulate few particle systems (to deduce information about the next steps of the particles) but those same particles move without spending any resources or concerns in the right direction. How can it be that humans should spend so many resources to deduce the next steps of few particle systems or protein folding, but the physical systems use no resources to deduce the right next steps.

How physical processes are connected with the information processing and deduction? How can it be that one system (human beings) should spend so many resources on deducing the same facts (i.e. the next steps) about some physical system which with its behavior deduces the same facts without spending no resources at all on the deduction process?

Comment: One way to look at this is that in Quantm Mechanics, anything that is not prohibited by the conservation laws is mandatory and will happen randomly according to its probability. This principle averages out to the classical laws of nature. So for particles it is not as much what to do, but what not to do. However, I hope you'll get a real answer.

Comment: It might just be a much more powerful computer

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a philosophy sort of problem, but I'd point out that the reason we spend so many resources calculating such things is because we are not using the most efficient calculator possible.  We want something more general purpose.

This is very evident when you look at AI and object recognition.  The human body has evolved to recognize objects for millions of years, and it is *very* efficient at it.  When we try to do it explicitly with computations, we find out just how hard it is to do it that way.

And we're not always less efficient.  Our calculations about stars are *extraordinarily* efficient compared to the stars which are burning hydrogen!

Comment: same with simulated physics engines, used to train AI in turbocharged time